# Generate all Calendar.app icons

Tags: macos, calendar

I'd like to get all 366 possible icons that Calendar would have displayed in the Dock.

How can you [automate the creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23842993) of each of these, either in Bash or Automator?

[image: calendar icon]

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid using Apple's artwork for your own projects or where you need to re-distribute the files. Apple's legal department may have an opinion.

Rather than copy Apple's artwork, create your own. There are numerous [collections of calendar artwork](http://www.flaticon.com/search/calendar) that you can build upon.

Use a scriptable tool like Gimp, Inkscape, or [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to create all 366 variations.